# Why did this mongoose search match these documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was trying to figure out if one of my users had any data associated with a goal with code "2" (which would have meant a bug) so I searched mongoose for

```
Entry.find({userid: req.user._id, 'goalSummary.2': {$exists: true}})
```

The `goalSummary` property is of type `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed` with keys identical to the goal codes (as strings, if that matters) and objects as values.

I got back 16 results, which each had `goalSummary`s like this:

```
goalSummary: {
    "1": {
        outcomes: 1,
        intendedcount: 1,
        extrascount: 0,
        notdonecount: 0,
        enough: "e"
    },
    "3": {
        outcomes: 1,
        intendedcount: 1,
        extrascount: 0,
        notdonecount: 0,
        enough: "e"
    },
    [...]
}
```

...ie no `2` key. Why could these have matched? Was 2 set to `undefined` but not deleted? It successfully didn't match hundreds of other entries.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a complete, reproducible example that includes your schema and a document your query unexpectedly returns?

Answer (score 0):

"field.2" only makes sense in Array types of mongoose properties. For Mixed, mongoose doesn't know *anything* about your document, so it will match everything, as long as there is a value.

On a side note, being burned myself and seeing others repeating it, I can also advice you too not to use keys for naming stuff. Rather do something like { key: 1, value: {outcomes: 1 ... }}.

Comment: But that's not what it did. It successfully didn't match items that used to have a value set for 2, but as far as I can tell the items it matched are those that never had a value set for 2 (or maybe had one set as undefined)

Comment: Also how did you get burned with those? They seem to be helpful for me in lots of instances, and I'm usually not querying by them (this was a one-off thing, not an endpoint).

Comment: When using aggregation. You want something like $sum: '$key' - it's a no go if the key value is the actual key. Kind of like: {books: 3, posts: 2}. If you have multiple such categories and don't know how many of each you may get (eg. articles, blogs...), you cannot aggregate -you would have to enumerate them all. So you have to fall back to mapreduce.

Comment: As for why it matched your "2" when there clearly isn't one, I can only speculate. If you have a "2", but it's undefined, then it's definitely matching the condition that it $exists. Otherwise, I'm not really sure.
Can you find a minimal reproducible version? Just two docs and simple data model I can test on my end and see if it is repeatable?

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that if you set something to `undefined` then mongo removed it and then it doesn't exist anymore (because it doesn't show up in the object, that I've seen). But if that's not how it works, then that might be the answer right there.

Comment: As it is, this was just a test I was doing; it's not actually blocking any code I'm currently trying to write, and I'm on tight deadlines, so it doesn't seem high priority to me to troubleshoot this.